# Different trace width signal transmission line

Tags: impedance-matching, trace

I have a really basic question. I am wondering what happens physically with the signal, if I have a change in a trace width (see picture below).

[image: diagram showing trace width changes]

My point of view is that you have a reflection of the signal, because of the different impedances. But I have heard that you can change the width for impedance matching, which you would need to reduce signal losses. However that would be contrary to the mentioned reflection. Can someone help me?

Comment: If your signal risetime is substantially slower than the electrical length of the "section", your circuit will not notice the section.